# DAX Calculate sum of values

Tags: sum, dax, calculated-columns

I have a table admissiontbl that records patients admissions.
Every patient has an *AdmittedDate*, *DischargedDAte* and *LengthOfStay* recorded.

| PatientID | AdmittedDate | DischargedDate | AdYear | Admonth | LengthOfStay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 02/01/2010 | 24/01/2010 | 2010 | 01 | 22 |
| 002 | 12/12/2009 | 18/12/2009 | 2009 | 12 | 7 |
| 003 | 12/12/2009 | 19/01/2010 | 2009 | 12 | 38 |

The LengthOfStay is calculated as `DischargedDAte - AdmittedDate`
**Problem:**
I will like to create a measure that sums up the LengthOfStay every month. This will include all patients discharged that month (i.e. including those admitted in the previous month or year).

**For Example:**
For Jan/2010, we want to calculate the SUM of LengthOfStay for ALL patients having their  DischargedDate in Jan/2010. This must include patients having their AdmittedDate =< Jan/2010.

**Scenario:**

**PatientID 003** was admitted on **12/12/2009** and discharged on **19/01/2010** will have his/her **LengthOfStay  = 38 days** when you calculate for Jan/2010.

**PatientID 002** was admitted on **12/12/2009** and discharged on **18/12/2009** will have his/her **LengthOfStay  = 7 days** when you calculate for Jan/2010.

**PatientID 001** was admitted on **02/01/2010** and discharged on **24/01/2010** will have his/her **LengthOfStay  = 22 days** when you calculate for Jan/2010.

Result:
The SUM of LengthOfStay = 38 + 7 + 22 = **67 days**

**Note:** The measure should take into account the month or year of the admission when calculating the SUM LengthOfStay.

I have tried the below DAX but it's not working

```
CM LOS Days = 
   Var CY = MAX(Admissions[Year])
   Var CM = MAX(Admissions[Month])

Return
CALCULATE(SUM(Admissions[LengthOfStay]),Admissions[AdYear]= CY && Admissions[AdMonth]<=CM)
```

Grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: please add the expected output.

Comment: Is not clear what do you want to calculate; Show as your desired result;

Comment: @Mr.Batra Thanks All for your comments. I have edited the question with some basic context

Comment: @msta42a Thanks All for your comments. I have edited the question with some basic context

Comment: Did you have a Calendar table with relationship to this patient table? What if some patient have AdmittedDate  <= Jan/2010 (for example Jan/ 1984 ? You want this also? )

Comment: @Mahmow add expected output sample also.

Comment: @Mr.Batra Result: **SUMOfLengthOfStay = 67** I intend to display the result on a card for my dashboard.

Comment: @msta42a Yes I have created a Calendar table with an active relationship with AdmittedDate. And Yes, it should calculate as long as the **DischargedDate** is in the month that you are calculating for.